# Gnosis safe refund amount is not equal to gas fee

Tags: gnosis-safe, safe-core-sdk

I am trying to enable a gas fee refund by referring to this [doc](https://github.com/safe-global/safe-contracts/blob/a6504a9afdeac186a8cdb29ad68b189523c80eda/docs/safe_tx_gas.md#with-gas-refund). The refund thing is working but I am not able to get the exact refund which is equal to the actual gas fee. The refund amount is either [less](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/0xdb9be835e1613be91283e72a0fc69a8e4700331a1c850a42e5d20b1f2a1dfcc2) or [more](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/0x3129f19e0bb0139c6521e633027cea971fb96abf28ce7bbd90b24ef801e0727b). I tried doing gas profiling and tried setting different values of `baseGas` and `gasPrice` using [tenderly](https://dashboard.tenderly.co/explorer?utm_source=homepage). Will appreciate if someone could look into this and guide on how to do the gnosis safe refund properly.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to figure out but there is no service which would return baseGas or recommended gasLimit for your safe transaction.

I could only find the way SafeTxGas is returned is by using below method.

```
/// @dev Allows to estimate a Safe transaction.
///      This method is only meant for estimation purpose, therefore the call will always revert and encode the result in the revert data.
///      Since the `estimateGas` function includes refunds, call this method to get an estimated of the costs that are deducted from the safe with `execTransaction`
/// @param to Destination address of Safe transaction.
/// @param value Ether value of Safe transaction.
/// @param data Data payload of Safe transaction.
/// @param operation Operation type of Safe transaction.
/// @return Estimate without refunds and overhead fees (base transaction and payload data gas costs).
/// @notice Deprecated in favor of common/StorageAccessible.sol and will be removed in next version.
function requiredTxGas(
    address to,
    uint256 value,
    bytes calldata data,
    Enum.Operation operation
) external returns (uint256) {
    uint256 startGas = gasleft();
    // We don't provide an error message here, as we use it to return the estimate
    require(execute(to, value, data, operation, gasleft()));
    uint256 requiredGas = startGas - gasleft();
    // Convert response to string and return via error message
    revert(string(abi.encodePacked(requiredGas)));
}
```

OR

```
/**
 * @dev Performs a delegatecall on a targetContract in the context of self.
 * Internally reverts execution to avoid side effects (making it static).
 *
 * This method reverts with data equal to `abi.encode(bool(success), bytes(response))`.
 * Specifically, the `returndata` after a call to this method will be:
 * `success:bool || response.length:uint256 || response:bytes`.
 *
 * @param targetContract Address of the contract containing the code to execute.
 * @param calldataPayload Calldata that should be sent to the target contract (encoded method name and arguments).
 */
function simulateAndRevert(address targetContract, bytes memory calldataPayload) external {
    // solhint-disable-next-line no-inline-assembly
    assembly {
        let success := delegatecall(gas(), targetContract, add(calldataPayload, 0x20), mload(calldataPayload), 0, 0)

        mstore(0x00, success)
        mstore(0x20, returndatasize())
        returndatacopy(0x40, 0, returndatasize())
        revert(0, add(returndatasize(), 0x40))
    }
}
```

regarding baseGas, waiting for the right answer from community.